# Помогите упростить условия и сделать код проще?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, условия

Задание:

> Write a function called check_date. check_date should require two positional parameters: a string representing the name of a month, and an integer representing a date. check_date should also have a keyword parameter called is_leap_year, assumed to be False, representing whether or not it's a leap year.
> Return True if the date is a valid calendar date. Return False if it is not. A date may not be a valid calendar date if the month isn't a real month, or if that date does not exist for that month.
> You can see some examples at the end of this file. Remember: 30 days has September, April, June, and November.
> All the rest have 31, except February, which has 28, until Leap Year gives it 29.
> You may assume that day will be greater than 0 (you don't need to check negative or zero values for day)

Для решения задачи, описанной выше написал следующий код:

```
def check_date(name_month, date, is_leap_year = False):
    if date in range (1,30) and is_leap_year == True and name_month == "February":
        return True
    elif date in range (1, 32) and name_month in ("October", "January", "August", "December", "March", "July"):
        return True
    elif date in range (1, 31) and name_month in ("September", "April", "June", "November"):
        return True
    elif name_month not in ("October", "January", "August", "December", "March", "July", "September", "April", "June", "November", "February"):
        return False
    else:
        return False
            
print(check_date("January", 31))
print(check_date("February", 29, is_leap_year = True))
print(check_date("Techtember", 15, is_leap_year = True))
print(check_date("June", 31))
```

Все прекрасно работает, но мне он не нравится - слишком много условий.
Подскажите как сделать код более простым?

PS Я новичок в изучении Python.
PPS Спасибо!

Comment: Все же SO на русском что подразумевает что копипаст английской задачи неуместен, даже учитывая что многие его способны прочитать.

Comment: кстати в коде кажется баг `check_date("February", 28) == False`

Comment: В конце видимо лишний `elif`, который возвращает `False`, при том, что `else` тоже возвращает `False`, т.е. эта проверка бессмысленна.

Comment: @alex да ты прав, если год не високосный, то любой день Февраля будет False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне больше нравится через словари:

```
def check_date(name_month: str, date: int, is_leap_year=False) -> bool:
    calendar = {'January': 31, 'February': 28, 'March': 31, 'April': 30, 'May': 31, 'June': 30, 'July': 31, 'August': 31, 'September': 30, 'October': 31, 'November': 30, 'December': 31,}

    if is_leap_year:
        calendar['February'] = 29

    return date <= calendar.get(name_month, False)
```

Нужно только установить максимальную дату февраля 29-е, если год високосный...

```
>>> check_date("January", 31)
True
>>> check_date("February", 29, is_leap_year = True)
True
>>> check_date("Techtember", 15, is_leap_year = True)
False
>>> check_date("June", 31)
False
```

[dict.get()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) вернет значение по ключу, либо default (необязательный параметр, None по-умолчанию): если месяц есть в словаре - вернет значение (дней), иначе вернет False (установленный вместо default)... дальше сравнивается date и то, что вернул dict.get() (инты с булевыми сравниваются в пайтоне преобразованием булевого в 1 или 0)

Comment: Спасибо! Не много не понимаю строку return calendar.get(name_month, False) >= date, а именно почему >=?

Comment: @АртемБагдасарян потому что мы сверяем чтобы дата не выходила за границы и значит она меньше или равна количеству дней (просто это обратная запись)

Comment: @АртемБагдасарян если date поставить впереди - понятнее? ;)

Comment: @Jack_oS блин, да))

Comment: `check_date("Not a month", 0) == True` и `check_date("February", -1) == True`

Comment: @alex "You may assume that day will be greater than 0 (you don't need to check negative or zero values for day", а при check_date("Not a month", 42) == False ;) можно 0 < date <= calendar.get(name_month, False)

Comment: @Jack_oS а в случае проверки отрицательных значений или нуля, нужна следующая строка - return 0 < date <= calendar.get(name_month, False)?

Comment: @АртемБагдасарян да, если в условии нет "you don't need to check negative or zero values for day"

Answer (score 4):

крадем из модуля datetime _MONTHNAMES и _DAYS_IN_MONTH

```
def check_date(name_month, date, is_leap_year=False):
    _MONTHNAMES = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    _DAYS_IN_MONTH = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

    if is_leap_year:
        _DAYS_IN_MONTH[1] = 29

    days_in_month = _DAYS_IN_MONTH[_MONTHNAMES.index(name_month)]
    return 0 < date <= days_in_month


print(check_date("Jan", 31))
print(check_date("Feb", 29, is_leap_year=True))
print(check_date("Feb", 28, is_leap_year=True))
print(check_date("Feb", 28))
print(check_date("Dec", 15, is_leap_year=True))
print(check_date("Jun", 31))
```